# IBM Liberty 19.0.0.11 return CWWKO0801E: Unable to initialize SSL connection

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I have added restConnector-2.0 feature in Liberty 19.0.0.11.
I changed configuration in server.xml file like below,

```
<basicRegistry id="bas" relam="BasicRealm">
   <user name="kin" password="password"/>
   <group name="admin">
     <member name="kin"></member>
   </group>
</basicRegistry>


 <administrator-role>
     <user>jayaramu</user>
     <group>admin</group>
   </administrator-role>
```

Then I ran the application server and try to validate database connection using below URL,
  https://localhost:9443/ibm/api/validation/dataSource/database

It return **CWWKO0801E: Unable to initialize SSL connection** error in console. 403 error in browser.

Comment: Hi - I notice that "realm" is misspelled in your basicRegistry config (spelled "relam") - it's possible that that is the problem.  If changing it to "realm" doesn't fix the problem, it might help to see the full server.xml config - or at least the portion containing the list of features and the SSL configuration.  You may need to ensure that your client has access to the same SSL certificates used on the server.  HTH

Comment: If messages.log shows you need to add a certificate to the trust store for ssl to work, here's how to do it. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_add_trust_cert.html